# Modify UITableView style after first display

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableView and after a flip animation I want modify the tableView style programmatically from grouped to plain, is it possible, if yes how?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant just change the style of a UITableView after its been created, therefore you should probably release your old table view and recreate a new one with the  style that you want...